# How do I write an if expression for current transform: translate() value?

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement, css-animations

I'm trying to create my first switch.

I have 2 keyframe animations. One to make the switch move right and the other to move the switch left.

Now, for the Javascript I think I need an if statement because I need Javascript to know what to do when the switch is in specific positions right?

The problem is I'm not quite sure what to put as the if expression.

I was hoping I could just use this as the if expression to return a boolean true value:

```
sliderCircle[0].style.transform = 'translate(0px, -20px)'
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-back"></div>
    <div class="slider-circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 55vw;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0 1vw;
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(255 ,255, 255, 0.4);
  transition: 1s;
}

.slider {
  height: 12px;
  margin-top: 2vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-back {
  width: 45px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(100deg, rgba(172,174,203,0.6) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 80%);
}

.slider-circle {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(100deg, rgba(172,174,203,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 80%);
  transform: translate(0, -20px);
}

.slide-anim-r {
  animation-name: slider-r;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

.slide-anim-l {
  animation-name: slider-l;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes slider-r {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, -20px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(22px, -20px);
  }
}

@keyframes slider-l {
  0% {
    transform: translate(22px, -20px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, -20px);
  }
}
```

Javascript:

```
const slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slider');  // slider toggle
const sliderCircle = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-circle');

slider[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (sliderCircle[0].style.transform = 'translate(0px, -20px)') {
    sliderCircle[0].classList.add('slide-anim-r');
    sliderCircle[0].style.transform = 'translate(22px, -20px)';
  } else {
    sliderCircle[0].classList.add('slide-anim-l');
    sliderCircle[0].style.transform = 'translate(0px, -20px)';
  }
});
```

At the moment I can click on the switch and it animates right but then I can't click on it to move it back again.

If anyone can advise a better way to do this please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: In your JavaScript if statements you are assigning with the = operator instead of testing for equality with ===. Try replacing = with === in the If clauses. I’m not entirely sure whether this will fix the issue however.

Comment: You don’t need an if statement at all. Just toggle the animation classes at the moment someone clicks the switch! `classList.toggle()`

Comment: @Kokodoko What would the syntax for toggle be here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have two states and you want to go from one to the other, just use a transition instead of an animation.

It is much simple, and you only need one additional class to define the second state. (*the first state being in the initial setup of the slider*)

```js
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');

sliders.forEach(slider => slider.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.currentTarget
    .querySelector('.slider-circle')
    .classList
    .toggle('slider-checked');

}))
```

```css
body {
  background: #bada55
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 55vw;
  padding: 0 1vw;
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  transition: 1s;
}

.slider {
  height: 12px;
  margin-top: 2vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-back {
  width: 45px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: linear-gradient(100deg, rgba(172, 174, 203, 0.6) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 80%);
}

.slider-circle {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: linear-gradient(100deg, rgba(172, 174, 203, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 80%);
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transform: translate(0, -20px);
}

.slider-circle.slider-checked {
  transform: translate(22px, -20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-back"></div>
    <div class="slider-circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-back"></div>
    <div class="slider-circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-back"></div>
    <div class="slider-circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great and I love that I can just repeat this code in html but I'd really like my animation to work rather than the switch snapping from left to right.

Comment: @Maximilian just add webkit vendor specific prefix for the relevant css and it will transition between them not just snap.